# MYSQL row fails to update with serialized array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to update a row with a serialized array, but the row is not updating when I run the SQL statement below.

However when I just use a word like TEST instead it updates.

Any help on clearing this up would be greatly appreciated.

Returns 0 rows affected:

```
UPDATE lists SET col1 = 'a:9:{i:0;s:7:"English";i:1;s:7:"Spanish";i:2;s:6:"Korean";i:3;s:4:"Thai";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";}' WHERE list_id =  '6'
```

Updates row correctly:

```
UPDATE lists SET col1 = 'TEST' WHERE list_id =  '6'
```

Below is the Codeigniter PHP function:

```
public function update_field($table, $field, $value, $whereField = FALSE, $whereValue = FALSE )
{

$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
if ($whereField === FALSE) {
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET $field = '$value'";
$query =  $this->db->query($sql);
} else {

    $data = array(
        $field => $value
    );

    $this->db->where($whereField, $whereValue);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);

}

if ($this->db->_error_message()) {

    echo 'Error Num: ' . $this->db->_error_number();  //returns 0 if query successful/no error
    echo '<br />Message: ' . $this->db->_error_message(); 
}

}
```

Comment: escape doubleqoutes and try and what is the col1 field in db i.e var char etc?

Comment: how is col1 defined? is it a CHAR? if so, make sure your value is not exceeding the max length for that column

Comment: col1 type is set to 'text' so I don't believe it's a length issue???

Comment: run the query in database query analyser if it works there then it is the problem when you are making string in php and passing it to db. if it fails in DB query analyser then what error it shows

Comment: If it is not giving any error then list_id = 6 does not exists in your table. I ran same query in mySQL and it inserted without giving any error.

Comment: I've run the exact SQL statement in PHPMmyadmin and it updates the row. I will add my PHP code to question, that seemingly works fine no all other queries

Comment: That's strange I copied and pasted the statement in PHPMYAdmin and this time 0 rows update...could it be a whitespace issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line is fine.

if you will try to update a field to it's current value (ie you make no actual changes) then you will get 0 updated rows.

for example, if i have an employees table:

```
employees
id    name      city
1     John      London

UPDATE `employees` SET `city` = "London" WHERE `id` = 1

// 0 rows affected
```

if you make no actual changes it returns 0

Comment: The issue isn't the line -- it looks like there is an issue in Codeigniter and passing serialized arrays.

Comment: $this->db->set('col', serialize(array('a'=>'b'))); works just fine

Comment: In my case when I serialized the array prior to passing it to the model it failed, but using active record in codeigntier when I serialized the array in the model it worked. Very strange. I posted a follow-up on the CI forum.